# Why must I slice an array to use it as a range in an alias parameter?

Tags: d

Ordinarily, I don't have to slice an array to treat it as a range.
However, when passing it as template alias parameter, it seems like I do:

```d
enum test(alias fun) = "it works";

immutable a = [1,2,3];

pragma(msg, test!(a[].map!(x => x))); // OK
pragma(msg, test!(a.map!(x => x)));   // map is not a member of a

// but a.map does work at runtime ...
unittest {
    auto r = a.map!(x => x);
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: Seems like a DMD bug; `map!(x=>x)(a)` works fine.

Comment: Reported: https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15870

Comment: It might be, that this is due to `a` and `a[]` having different types (`a = immutable(int[])` and `a[] = immutable(int)[]`)